# How to append headers to certain routes and not all

Tags: angular

I am trying to update my angular Http and Headers to angular 4 HttpClient and HttpHeaders module. The problem I am having is I want to add authenication headers to only one or two routes and not all of my routes. Many of the tutorials I am finding only show me how to update the headers for ALL routes and I do not fully understand the angular.io headers api to update my code.

My old code

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

constructor(private http: Http) { }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, { headers: headers });
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getProfile() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', { headers: headers });
      .map(res => res.json());
```

new code

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, httpOptions);
  }

  getProfile() {
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);  <---- not sure what to do with this    
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', httpOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a factory function to create `httpOptions` each time, and pass it parameters to define what headers are required.

```
private getOptions(authToken?: string) {
   const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
   };
   if(authToken) {
       httpOptions.headers.append('Authorization', authToken);
   }
   return httpOptions;
}

authenticateUser(user) {
     return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, this.getOptions()).map(res => res.json());
}

getProfile() {
    const token = this.loadToken();
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', this.getOptions(token));
}
```